# QGis and Geomedia via Oracle

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, geomedia

When I use both QGis and Geomedia to digitize in the same layer I get some issues in my Oracle table. It looks like Geomedia save my point, lines and polygons as ARRAY, while QGis save it like POINT (to points) and ARRAY (to lines and polygons). The problem cames when a point layer is worked both with Geomedia and QGis --> In my Oracle table all the points digitized with QGis after a point digitized with Geomedia are "snapped" in the Point (coordinate) digitized with Geomedia. Any idea to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you mean that Geomedia encodes point A (Xa, Ya) as

```
sdo_geometry (2001, <srid>, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,1,1), sdo_ordinate_array (Xa, Ya))
```

while QGis saves it as

```
sdo_geometry (2001, <srid>, sdo_point_type (Xa, Ya, null), null, null)
```

Both notations are perfectly legal and valid. If QGis does not understand the first notation, then this is a bug in QGis.

Comment: can you please log the bug in hub.qgis.org if you haven't already